# How to insert data into mysql with order

Tags: sql, insert

If Insert SQL without "order by", the records in the sql are arranged by insert time.

I have a table: authorization( pin, code)

However, I run INSERT INTO authorization(pin, code)
            VALUES ('12', 'abcd').
After insert few records, I query all the data and find that these records have no order.

How can I insert data with the insert time order.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in SQL have no inherent ordering.  That is the definition of the language.  What you want to do is to add an autoincrement id column into your data:

```
create table authorization (
    AuthorizationID int auto_increment primary key,
    pin . . .
    code . . .
    . . .
);
```

Then when you insert as:

```
insert into authorization(pin, code)
    . . .;
```

A new id will be generated automatically.  This `id` will remember the insert order.  By the way, you might also want a timestamp column, if you want to remember the exact time of the insert as well.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you, The problem is solved! Now I need to review knowledge of SQL. :P